# Jenkins pipeline - How to read the success status of build?

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is the output after running the build(with success):

```
$ sam build
2019-06-02 15:36:37 Building resource 'SomeFunction'
2019-06-02 15:36:37 Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
2019-06-02 15:36:39 Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource

Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam/build
Built Template   : .aws-sam/build/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
[*] Package: sam package --s3-bucket <yourbucket>
```

---

`[command] && echo "Yes"` approach did not help me.

I tried to use this in Jenkins pipeline

```
def samAppBuildStatus =  sh(script: '[cd sam-app-folder; sam build  | grep 'Succeeded' ] && echo true', returnStatus: true) as Boolean
```

as one-liner script command, but does not work

---

How to grab the success build status using bash script? for Jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Use this to grab the exit status of the command:

```
def samAppBuildStatus = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'cd sam-app-folder; sam build | grep "Succeeded"'
```

or this if you don't want to see any `stderr` in the output:

```
def samAppBuildStatus = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'cd sam-app-folder; sam build 2>&1 | grep "Succeeded"'
```

then later in your `Jenkinsfile` you can do something like this:

```
if (!samAppBuildStatus){
    echo "build success [$samAppBuildStatus]"
} else {
    echo "build failed [$samAppBuildStatus]"
}
```

The reason for the `!` is because the definitions of `true` and `false` between shell and groovy differ (`0` is `true` for shell).

Comment: First 3 lines of output is written to stderr. Remaining lines are written to stdout

Comment: @overexchange , modified to use `returnStatus` instead.

Comment: But this command writes output to console. Is it recommended?

Comment: @overexchange , can you clarify what you mean? Which command are you talking about? The `if` statement or the definition of `samAppBuildStatus`? Which console? The slave or on the master?

Comment: `sam build` output

Comment: As it is currently `sam build | grep "Succeeded"` only the `Succeeded` will show in the output (in the event of a fail nothing will show). I don't see anything wrong with that, is that something you are trying to fix/mitigate?

Comment: No, will show first 3 lines(on stderr) and then `Build Succeeded`(stdout). You can veri

Comment: @overexchange , modified to remove `stderr`.

Comment: `{ cd folder; sam build 1>&2; } 2>&1 | grep -q Succeeded && echo "Yes"` this will not change the current working directory. Do you think this is too much complicated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196330/discussion-between-perplexabot-and-overexchange).