# How stdout-stderr work with docker containers?

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, stdout, docker-machine

I remember that, `stdin`, `stdout` & `stderr` are first 3 entries of file descriptor table in [Process control block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block).

---

On a AWS EC2 instance(`host1`), We have jenkins slave(say `slave-container`).

`slave-container` consist of docker client that talks to docker daemon running on `host1`

`slave-container` launches another docker container(say `build-container` to build source code) on `host1`.

Below is the pipeline output from `slave-container`:

```
Running on slave-container in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/abc-app
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Buildabcapp)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . 111111111110.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/abc-build:7-jdk.x.2
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
slave-container seems to be running inside container 55664444444444444444444444444444444444444444
$ docker run -t -d -u 9000:9000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/abc-app --volumes-from 55664444444444444444444444444444444444444444  111111111110.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/abc-build:7-jdk.x.2 cat
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep -q success
+ echo Yes
```

Above `docker run` command launches `build-container` that runs shell commands that gives output on `stdout` of `slave-container`:

```
+ grep -q success
+ echo Yes
```

---

How stdout/stderr of `build-container` shown on stdout of `slave-container`?

Comment: See! `{}` has nothing to do with suppressing outputs (as discussed with you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960876/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-read-the-success-status-of-build/56962094#56962094). Also instead of integrating all your things together then start trying to figure things out, I would do one step at a time. Jenkins is the important factor here, not docker I believe.

Comment: @Perplexabot  Jenkins is running in docker container

Comment: Anything with a `+` before it is most likely due to `Jenkins` not `docker`

Answer (score 1):

The Docker Engine exposes an API that is consumed by the docker client when you run different commands.

In the particular case of running `docker run` without the `-d` parameter the client uses the endpoints:

`POST /containers/create` - For creating the container

`POST /containers/(id or name)/attach` - For attaching to the container and stream the stdout and stderr to the client.

For more information check the API docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#31-containers

Comment: But in my case... it has `-d`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your unexpected behavior is because `Jenkins` runs all `sh` functions with `set -x` prior to the actual shell commands. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do) if you are not familiar with `set -x`.

This can be proved by inspecting `Jenkins` [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/Shell.java) for the `sh` function, look:

```
public String[] buildCommandLine(FilePath script) {
    if(command.startsWith("#!")) {
        // interpreter override
        int end = command.indexOf('\n');
        if(end<0)   end=command.length();
        List<String> args = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Util.tokenize(command.substring(0, end).trim())));
        args.add(script.getRemote());
        args.set(0,args.get(0).substring(2));   // trim off "#!"
        return args.toArray(new String[0]);
    } else
        return new String[] { getDescriptor().getShellOrDefault(script.getChannel()), "-xe", script.getRemote()};
}
```

As you can see in the default case it runs with a `set -x` and `set -e`.
You can override that behavior by preceding your script with a `shebang`.

Comment: Those commands are coming from docker container that has no jenkins... please check the `docker run` command that has image argument(`55664444444444444444444444444444444444444444 `)

Comment: I see the line you are talking about and I still think this is related to `Jenkins` vs `docker` .
I think it would be useful if you add the relevant portion of your `Jenkinsfile` .